# Team recording bot from scratch(error at response)

Tags: botframework, .net-4.8

[image] We are creating a recording bot in .netframework 4.7.2 using the bot framework. We are making this bot from scratch. we were stuck at one point. please see the image below to see the error we are facing: What we are trying to do is we are making a bot controller and in that, we are getting an error at ( await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot)) response. please see the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute;

namespace ScratchTeamrecordingBot.Controllers
{
   
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/messages")]     
        public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
            private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter Adapter;
            private readonly IBot Bot;

            public HomeController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
            {
                Adapter = adapter;
                Bot = bot;
            }

            [HttpPost, HttpGet]
            public async Task PostAsync()
            {
                // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
                // The adapter will invoke the bot.
                await Adapter.ProcessAsync`(Request, Response, Bot);
            }
        }
    
}

We are creating a recording bot in .netframework 4.7.2 using the bot framework. We are making this bot from scratch. we were stuck at one point. please see the image below to see the error we are facing: What we are trying to do is we are making a bot controller and in that, we are getting an error at ( await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot)) response. please see the code below:
```

Comment: You need to tell us what the error actually is. The red squiggly line doesn't tell us anything. Have you checked the API reference to see if you're using that function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **View > Error List** in Visual Studio and check the error message. But probably, your error is because you are using .Net Framework. If you check the type of the `Response` object you will see is type of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpResponse.IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter` . My recomendation is to use .Net Core for your project.

For information about the IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.integration.aspnet.core.ibotframeworkhttpadapter?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

Hope you find this information useful :)

Best regard!